# How can I configure HTTrack to work via Tor Browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

Can anybody describe, how to configure HTTrack to work via the Tor Browser Bundle?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Command line: `httrack www.foobar.com/page.html -P localhost:9150`
or if you use the gui then set the proxy server to `localhost` and the proxy port to `9150`.
Make sure that Tor Browser Bundle is open otherwise it won't work.
Note that some anonymity will be lost in that parties from the exit node onwards (such as the exit node, the website and NSA) will know that you are using Httrack and not Tor browser.